# List Individual invoices that have empty state fields

Tags: sql

I was given code that lists states and the invoice totals for that state based on ship to address from our ERP software. There is the issue were someone forgot to put in a state so we have a total that is not associated with a state. We need to find out those invoices that do not have a state so we can update the state field in the ERP software.

Example

```
100.00  GA
200.00  EMPTY
300.00  IN
```

I have very limited skills in SQL and am using what was given to me when I filled this position.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Invoice_Header.Orig_Invoice_Amt) AS SumOfOrig_Invoice_Amt,
    Address.State
FROM Address 
INNER JOIN Invoice_Header ON Address.Address = Invoice_Header.Ship_To
WHERE Invoice_Header.Document_Date Between '1/1/2018' And '12/31/2018'
GROUP BY Address.State;
```

A list of invoices that do not have a state associated with them so we can go into the ERP Software and add the state.

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE state = 'EMPTY'` or maybe `WHERE state IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will identify all invoiced customers (`Ship_To`) that do not have a `State` in table `Address` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.Ship_To, a.Address
FROM Invoice_Header i
LEFT JOIN Address a ON a.Address = i.Ship_To
WHERE a.State IS NULL AND i.Document_Date Between '1/1/2018' And '12/31/2018'
```

There could be two reasons for this :

- either there is no record in `Address` for that customer ; when this happens, the second column in the results is empty
- either there is an `Address` record, but which as an empty `State`

Comment: I tried the code and I am getting the following Error message  The multi-part identifier "Invoice_Header.Document_Date" could not be bound.